# Any problems in this rwlock implementation?

Tags: c, locking

I just implemented a reader-writer lock in C. I want to limit the number of readers, so I use 'num' to count it. I'm not sure whether this implementation has some potential data race or deadlock conditions. So could you help me figuring them out please?

Another question is can I remove the 'spin_lock' in struct _rwlock in someway? Thanks!

```
#define MAX_READER 16; 
typedef _rwlock *rwlock;
struct _rwlock{
    spin_lock   lk;
    unint32_t   num;
};
void wr_lock(rwlock lock){
    while (1){
        if (lock->num > 0) continue;
        lock(lock->lk);
        lock->num += MAX_READER;
        return;
    }
}
void wr_unlock(rwlock lock){
    lock->num -= MAX_READER;
    unlock(lock->lk);
}
void rd_lock(rwlock lock){
    while (1){
        if (lock->num >= MAX_READER) continue;
        atom_inc(num);
        return;
    }
}
void rd_unlock(rwlock lock){
    atom_dec(num);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be the CPU on that machine when a couple-hundred threads line up to acquire the write lock. Also, there is zero protection when checking the predicates, only when modifying them, you're assuming an implied barrier in at least two places. Any reason you're not using pthread rwlocks ?

Comment: I just want to see how rwlock works by implementing one by myself. And I came up with an idea and implemented it.

Comment: @WDan: for almost any system that has a built-in rwlock implementation, the answer to "how it works" will be "not like anything that it's possible to write using only standard functions", because their rwlock implementation can use futexes (in the case of Linux) and/or interact directly with the kernel/scheduler. They might use spinlocks, but only for locks that are held very briefly. They won't hold a spinlock while executing user code because the cost of another thread spinning that whole time is too high.

Comment: And the sad thing, native kernel *documented* RW-locks were not introduces into Win32/64 until the vista/server2k8 kernels. Yeah, MS can bite me.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, there are severe issues here. I don't know what synchronization library you are using, but you are not protecting access to shared data and you will waste tons of CPU cycles on your loops in rd_lock() and wr_lock(). Spin locks should be avoided in virtually all cases (there are exceptions though).

Comment: Thank you! And I don't totally understand what do you mean by not protecting access to shared data. In this case, the shared data may be num only. In reader's operations, I use atomic update operation to handle num. In writer's operatioins, I think the spin_lock protects it. If you mean the 'continue' sentence wastes the CPU time, 'yield' can be used to replace it. Yeah, I don't think using spinlock is a good idea. That's why I want to remove it :)

Comment: Don't you have access to something like pthreads? Use that to eliminate your spin locks. You have to protect both reading and writing to your data. You don't protect your reads. I wouldn't say that yield is a solution to the problems with spin locks, but it can give drastic improvements. Still I'm quite sure that there are better ways. What's your target system?

Comment: You're right, I should protect the reads. It's linux. How can pthreads eliminate the spin locks? Use the mutex in pthreads?

Comment: It seems mutex will block rather than spin-loop in case acquiring a lock failed. I have some confusion in mutex, spin-lock, semaphore and cv etc...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In `wr_lock` (and similar in `rd_lock`):

```
while (1){
    if (lock->num > 0) continue;
```

This is wrong. If you don't somehow synchronize, you aren't guaranteed to see changes from other threads. If this were the only problem you could perhaps acquire the lock and then check the count.

In `rd_lock`:

```
atom_inc(num);
```

This doesn't play well with the non-atomic `+=` and `-=` in the writer functions, because it can interrupt them. Same for the decrement in `rd_unlock`.

`rd_lock` can return while a thread holds the lock as writer -- this isn't the usual semantics of a reader-writer lock, and it means that whatever your rw-lock is supposed to protect, it will not protect it.

If you are using pthreads, then it already has a rwlock. On Windows consider SRWlocks (never used 'em myself). For portable code, build your rwlock using a condition variable (or maybe two -- one for readers and one for writers). That is, insofar as multi-threaded code in C *can* be portable. C11 has a condition variable, and if there's a pre-C11 threads implementation out there that doesn't, I don't want to have to use it ;-)

Comment: You mean rd_lock may return while a thread holds the lock as writer because I read lock->num in rd_lock without synchronization? I don't know the accurate implementation of rwlock, and I want to know how it works. So I implemented my edition for a test. I take http://locklessinc.com/articles/locks/ as a reference before.

Comment: `rd_lock` can return while a writer "holds the lock" because there's absolutely nothing in `rd_lock` that even tries to prevent this from happening. You could improve matters by taking the spinlock in `rd_lock` while you check and increment the reader count, but it's not a complete solution.

Comment: I once thought when a writer holds the lock, the 'num' should be equal  to MAX_READER since the writer add MAX_READER to num in function wr_lock. And the rd_lock will loop until the writer is finished.

Comment: @WDan: there's a gap between the writer checking `num`, and the writer increasing `num`. During that gap, any number of reader threads can get through.